# Finding median of two sorted arrays. Can some inequality checks be eliminated?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search, median

Working on this problem and post code, my question is whether it is safe to change this line of code

```
j > 0 and i < m and B[j-1] > A[i]
```

to

```
i < m and B[j-1] > A[i]
```

and also it is safe to change this line of code

```
i > 0 and j < n and A[i-1] > B[j]
```

to

```
i > 0 and A[i-1] > B[j]
```

I think remove the condition check of `j` is safe since we already making sure size of `A` is no bigger than size of `B`.

**Problem statement**

There are two sorted arrays `nums1` and `nums2` of size `m` and `n` respectively. Find the median of the two sorted arrays. The overall run time complexity should be O(log (m+n)).

**Implementation**

```
 def median(A, B):
    m, n = len(A), len(B)
    if m > n:
        A, B, m, n = B, A, n, m
    if n == 0:
        raise ValueError

    imin, imax, half_len = 0, m, (m + n + 1) / 2
    while imin <= imax:
        i = (imin + imax) / 2
        j = half_len - i
        if j > 0 and i < m and B[j-1] > A[i]:
            # i is too small, must increase it
            imin = i + 1
        elif i > 0 and j < n and A[i-1] > B[j]:
            # i is too big, must decrease it
            imax = i - 1
        else:
            # i is perfect
            if i == 0: max_of_left = B[j-1]
            elif j == 0: max_of_left = A[i-1]
            else: max_of_left = max(A[i-1], B[j-1])

            if (m + n) % 2 == 1:
                return max_of_left

            if i == m: min_of_right = B[j]
            elif j == n: min_of_right = A[i]
            else: min_of_right = min(A[i], B[j])

            return (max_of_left + min_of_right) / 2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Jens, more elegant now. :)

Comment: Apparently your code is working, so this seems more suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @schwobaseggl, you mean removing additional check on `j` works? Or original code works? I just want to remove unnecessarily checking to make code more simple and clean.

Comment: @LinMa Which is the exact kind of question for code review: having code that does what it is supposed to do, but might be shortened, boosted, or otherwise improved

Comment: @Samufi, what do you mean "indices are integers"?

Comment: @LinMa Sorry, I guess you are using Python 2? In Python 3 it is e.g. `(3 + 4)  / 2 == 3.5`. That is, your indices could become floats. But since the other users seem to be able to run your code, this might not be an issue (in Python 2). I therefore deleted my comment.

Comment: @Samufi, yes, I am using Python 2.7.x, I should state clearly, thanks. Any comments on my original question, whether safe to remove additional check on `j`? Thanks.

Comment: @schwobaseggl This [cross-post](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/125263/9357) is marginally acceptable on Code Review, as it is not necessarily seeking an open-ended critique. It's fine as a Stack Overflow question, though, because there is a specific question about the code. Please see [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think, you can remove the condition `j > 0`, because

```
j = half_len - i
```

and  you already check that `i<m` and `(m + n + 1) / 2` must be bigger than `m` since `n>=m`

same for the second condition `j < n`. You already make sure that `i>0`, which ensures that `j` can at most be `(2n+1)/2 - 1` which is smaller than n and thus automatically satisfies your condition

Comment: Thanks Alexander, vote up. Wondering if removing check on `j` also works for the case when `m==n` (i.e. two array same size)?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure. I actually meant to write n>=m. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for the help, mark your answer as reply and vote up. :)